# Perl DES CBC encryption results in more bytes

Tags: perl, encryption, des, cbc-mode

I am using Perl to perform CBC DES encryption using the Crypt::CBC library:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use Crypt::CBC;
$key  = "\x4A\x6F\xC2\x2A\x44\xE2\xA4\x48"; 
$iv   = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
$data = "\x51\x55\x45\x53\x54\x49\x4F\x4E";

print "TXT->", $data, "\n";
print "HEX->", unpack("H*", $data), "\n";
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-literal_key => 1,
                    -key         => $key,
                    -iv          => $iv,
                    -header      => 'none');

$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($data);
print "ENC->", unpack("H*", $ciphertext), "\n";
```

The output of the code is:

```
TXT->QUESTION
HEX->5155455354494f4e
ENC->8220553e09f1b31ba7691f3f7fb52416
```

My data is conveniently of size 64bits (16 hex digits) which is in accordance with the DES standard. According to Wikipedia

> DES is the archetypal block cipher — an algorithm that takes a fixed-length string of plaintext bits and transforms it through a series of complicated operations into another ciphertext bitstring of the **same length**

Why is it that the encoded output is of longer byte length than the original input?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Working backward from the second block (a7691f3f7fb52416) gives 8a285d3601f9bb13, and XORed with the first block (8220553e09f1b31b) gives 0808080808080808 (HEX).  Something is producing the block value of 0808080808080808 as a second input block value.

[image: CBC Values]

So all you have to do is figure out where the backspace characters came from as a second block input.

See https://metacpan.org/pod/Crypt::CBC

This:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use Crypt::CBC;
$key  = "\x4A\x6F\xC2\x2A\x44\xE2\xA4\x48"; 
$iv   = "\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00";
$data = "\x51\x55\x45\x53\x54\x49\x4F\x4E";

print "TXT->", $data, "\n";
print "HEX->", unpack("H*", $data), "\n";
$cipher = Crypt::CBC->new(-literal_key => 1,
                    -key         => $key,
                    -iv          => $iv,
                    -header      => 'none',
                    -padding     => 'null');

$ciphertext = $cipher->encrypt($data);

print "ENC->", unpack("H*", $ciphertext), "\n";
```

Gave:

> david_koontz@Macbook: cbc_des
>   TXT->QUESTION
>   HEX->5155455354494f4e
>   ENC->8220553e09f1b31b
>   david_koontz@Macbook:

I made the mistake poking around because I know a fair bit about DES, not so much perl.

Adding the padding null seemed to do the trick, after I learned how to add Crypt::CBC and Crypt::DES to a perl library.

I used http://code.google.com/p/dpades/source/browse/trunk/simu_js/JS-DES.html to do the encryptions and decryptions necessary to figure out what's going on.  Use the view raw file button and save JS-DES.html locally, open it with a browser.

Comment: Thank you David, this really helped, I never considered working backward. I see now that the "standard" padding option will pad with 01 if there is one free byte and 0202 if there is two free bytes and 030303 if there are three free bytes etc. Why they pad an fully empty block is beyond me however your answer has solved my issue.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know about the padding bytes.  My eyes glazed over looking in CBC.pm.

Answer (score 0):

The encrypted message is longer because it includes the IV. BTW, a fixed IV does not make sense, it should be random and newly generated for each message.

Comment: Uh, no. See the answer on padding, note the block diagram showing how the initial vector is combined with plaintext.  The problem appears to be unintended padding, a block of backspace characters.